# JavaScript arrow function to count time it gets called but does not take any parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I receive a challenge to create a function (arrow function) that count the times it gets called or invoked. BUT, this function can't take any parameter or interact with outside scope likes the normal way below.

Normal way:

```
var count = 0;
var countTimesCalled = (count) => {
  count+=1;
  return count;
}

console.log(countTimesCalled(count))
```

Is it possible to have created a function that does not take any parameter and not interact with outside scope to count the times it gets called? Where to store the times (var count) on runtime and after runtime?

Please help!

Comment: Would that original one even work the way it's intended to? I'm pretty sure the global `count` would just remain 0 as at no point do you do `count = countTimesCalled(count)`

Comment: Use an IIFE to create a local scope containing the function.

Comment: Your "normal way" does not even work as the incremented `count` is your local parameter variable

Comment: Please define what exactly would count as "interact with outside scope".

Comment: "not interact with the outside scope", i mean the function should be entirely self-contained, it should not rely on any code other than that contained in its own body

Answer (score 4):

Use an IIFE to hold the `count` variable in a local scope:

```js
var countTimesCalled = (() => {
  var count = 0;
  return () => ++count;
})();
console.log(countTimesCalled());
console.log(countTimesCalled());
console.log(countTimesCalled());
```

Answer (score 1):

> not interact with outside scope

That is not possible, but you could do something that looks kind of like it does that:

```js
var countTimesCalled = (count => _ => ++count)(0);

console.log(countTimesCalled());
console.log(countTimesCalled());
console.log(countTimesCalled());
```

In reality there are two arrow functions there, an outer one to hold the count variable that is called once, and an inner one that is returned and referenced by `countTimesCalled`. That inner one is interacting with a scope outside of itself, but only as far out as the outer arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.bind` to capture state, if you really wanted to avoid accessing another closure scope entirely, e.g.

```
var countTimesCalled = function() { 
  return this.counter++ 
}.bind({ counter: 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an attribute to the function, i.e: `countTimesCalled.i`

```js
var countTimesCalled = () => (countTimesCalled.i = (countTimesCalled.i || 0) + 1);

console.log(countTimesCalled())
console.log(countTimesCalled())
console.log(countTimesCalled())
```